# Oracle - Creating Triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger in Oracle whereby we move deleted records to another table. So when deleted column is set to 1, it should move the records from the patient_table to the deleted_patient_table.

Can you please help :)

```
CREATE TABLE Patient_Table(
PatientID NUMBER(6) Primary Key,
Title char(4) NOT NULL,
Forename varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Surname varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Gender char(1) NOT NULL CHECK (Gender in ('M','F')),
DOB date NOT NULL,
TelNo varchar(12) NOT NULL,
Conditions varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Deleted Number(1) NOT NULL CHECK (Deleted  in ('0','1'));
```

-- Table that should contain deleted records --

```
Create Table Deleted_Patient_table(
PatientID NUMBER(6) Primary Key,
Title char(4) NOT NULL,
Forename varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Surname varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Gender char(1) NOT NULL CHECK (Gender in ('M','F')),
DOB date NOT NULL,
TelNo varchar(12) NOT NULL,
Conditions varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Deleted Number(1));
```

Comment: When you say *" it should move the records"* do you mean that at the end of the operation the record should be in **only** `Deleted_Patient_table` rather than in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create or replace trigger trg_del 
  Before delete on Patient_Table
  for each row
Begin
  Insert into Deleted_Patient_table value (:old.PatientID,...)
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're soft-deleting your rows. i.e. not deleting but updating related column(`Deleted`) from `0` to `1`. The values of column can be one of `two` and `not null`, so you only need to compare only two values of them without `nvl` operator. During this `update` operation you can use below trigger to produce `log records` :

```
Create or Replace Trigger Trg_Del_Patient 
After Update on Patient_Table 
For Each Row 
Begin 
 If ( :old.Deleted = 0 and :new.Deleted = 1 ) Then
  Insert into Deleted_Patient_table 
  values(:old.PatientID,:old.Title,:old.Forename,:old.Surname,
         :old.Gender,:old.DOB,:old.TelNo,:old.Conditions);
  Delete Patient_Table where PatientID = :old.PatientID; 
  -- Include this Delete statement, if you want to remove after the row has been inserted to the Deleted_Patient_Table 
 End If;
End;
```

Comment: Hi Barbaros, Thanks for your help. We have managed to move the record to the Deleted_Patient_Table, however it now appears in both tables. How can we remove it from the Patient_table after the row has been moved to the Deleted_Patient_Table. Cheers, Ibs :)

Comment: @Ibs you can use `delete Patient_Table where PatientID = :old.PatientID;` just after `Insert` statement to manage this task.